# React SVG style element on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have an array of squares inside SVG-based React component and I need to apply custom style (`fill` color set to `purple`) to square under cursor on hover.

I tried that with both CSS :hover and `onMouseOver` events, neither did work.

Any clues are much appreciated

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const Matrix = ({m, n}) => (
    <svg 
      viewBox={`0 0 ${m*10+10} ${n*10+10}`} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <defs>
          <rect 
            id="cell" 
            width="5" 
            height="5"
            className="cell"
            onMouseOver={({target}) => target.style.cssText="fill:purple"}
          />
      </defs>
      <g>
        {
          Array(n).fill().map((row, rowIdx) => (
            <g key={rowIdx}>
              {
                Array(m).fill().map((col, colIdx) => (
                    <g key={colIdx}>
                      <use 
                        x={5+colIdx*5} 
                        y={5+rowIdx*5} 
                        xlinkHref="#cell"
                        fill="lightgray"
                        stroke="white"
                        strokeWidth=".4" 
                      />
                    </g>
                ))
              }
            </g>
          ))
        }
      </g>
  </svg>
)

render (
  <Matrix m={10} n={10} />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
#cell:hover {
  fill: purple;
}

.cell:hover {
  fill: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You are trying to color each square? or the big one behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to color each square you must have to use your class `.cell` inside the `<use />` of each cell:

```
<use 
 className="cell"
 x={5+colIdx*5} 
 y={5+rowIdx*5} 
 xlinkHref="#cell"
 fill="grey"
 stroke="white"
 strokeWidth=".4" 
/>
```

And now you can use your css style:

```
.cell:hover {
  fill: purple;
}
```

Snippet:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const Matrix = ({m, n}) => (
    <svg 
      viewBox={`0 0 ${m*10+10} ${n*10+10}`} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <defs>
          <rect 
            id="cell" 
            width="5" 
            height="5"
          />
      </defs>
      <g>
        {
          Array(n).fill().map((row, rowIdx) => (
            <g key={rowIdx}>
              {
                Array(m).fill().map((col, colIdx) => (
                    <g key={colIdx}>
                      <use 
                        className="cell"
                        x={5+colIdx*5} 
                        y={5+rowIdx*5} 
                        xlinkHref="#cell"
                        fill="grey"
                        stroke="white"
                        strokeWidth=".4" 
                      />
                    </g>
                ))
              }
            </g>
          ))
        }
      </g>
  </svg>
)

render (
  <Matrix m={10} n={10} />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
.cell:hover {
  fill: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script></script><div id="root"></div>
```